# Get data from an HTML table into an Access database

Tags: html, sql, ms-access, html-parsing

How I can fill a database dynamically from a HTML table (e.g., from Market data S&P 500)?

I have an account with [Yahoo! Financial](http://finance.yahoo.com/). In the account I can view financial data in HTML.

I need a simple tool to fill a data base (Access), from an HTML table. Where can I find a tool like that?

Answer (score 2):

ACE/Jet OLEDB can be used to import data directly from an HTML file. For example, given an *existing* Access table [DataFromHtml]

```
ID  LastName
--  --------
```

and an HTML file containing a table

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>
        Test Data
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            ID
        </th>
        <th>
            LastName
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            1
        </td>
        <td>
            Thompson
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            2
        </td>
        <td>
            O'Rourke
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

the following VBA code will clear out the Access table (`DELETE FROM`) and then import the HTML table data into it.

```
Sub ImportFromHtml()
Const LocalTableName = "DataFromHtml"
Dim con As Object, rstHtml As Object, fld As Object, _
        cdb As DAO.Database, rstAccdb As DAO.Recordset, _
        recCount As Long

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.Open _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\Gord\Documents\table.htm;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""HTML Import;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"
Set rstHtml = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rstHtml.Open "SELECT * FROM [Test Data]", con

Set cdb = CurrentDb
cdb.Execute "DELETE FROM [" & LocalTableName & "]", dbFailOnError
Set rstAccdb = cdb.OpenRecordset(LocalTableName, dbOpenTable)

recCount = 0
Do While Not rstHtml.EOF
    recCount = recCount + 1
    rstAccdb.AddNew
    For Each fld In rstHtml.Fields
        rstAccdb.Fields(Trim(fld.Name)).Value = Trim(fld.Value)
    Next
    Set fld = Nothing
    rstAccdb.Update
    rstHtml.MoveNext
Loop

rstAccdb.Close
Set rstAccdb = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing

rstHtml.Close
Set rstHtml = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing

Debug.Print recCount & " record(s) imported"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can export as CSV from Yahoo historical data and link that csv file in Access as a MS Access Table directly. http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/import-or-link-to-data-in-a-text-file-HA001232227.aspx

If you want to deal with the html page source then this link may help.

http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?p=1145646

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but hopefully my solution will help someone.
I recently receive a huge number of tables in separate html files.  These files were exported from an Oracle/Unix system; a version prior to the one with the csv export.
I have MS-Access 365 on Win10 and SSD.
I first tried the solution above but that seemed to be as slow as importing each html manually.
So I tried a different approach. I added a reference to the "Microsoft HTML Object Library".
The only caveat is: it is not dynamic: I didn't add code to map each column but one could create a table on the fly.

```
' import a table from a local html file into a similar Access table
Function Import(FileName As String, TableName As String) As Long ' returns number of rows
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject ' faster and proper read of \n
Dim ts As TextStream
Dim fld As Long, rows As Long, bt As Long, tm As Single
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim doc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim trTag As Object
Dim tdTag As Object
On Error GoTo errH
    Debug.Print "Loading " & FileName
If Dir(FileName) > " " Then
    tm = Timer
    bt = FileLen(FileName)
    Set ts = FSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)
    doc.body.innerHTML = ts.ReadAll
    Do Until doc.ReadyState = "complete"  ' 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    ts.Close
    Debug.Print "Loaded " & bt & " bytes in " & (Timer - tm) & " seconds. "
Else
    MsgBox "File not exist"
    Exit Function
End If
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM [" & TableName & "]", dbFailOnError
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(TableName, dbOpenTable)
    Debug.Print "Destination has " & rs.Fields.Count & " fields (starting at 0)."
For Each trTag In doc.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    If rows > 0 Then
        rs.AddNew ' first row contains header. Some column names MSaccess don't like
        fld = 0
    End If
    For Each tdTag In trTag.childNodes()
        fld = fld + 1 'field counter
        If rows = 0 Then
            Debug.Print tdTag.innerText; "|"; ' field names from source
        Else
            ' add field
            rs.Fields(fld) = Trim(tdTag.innerText) ' When null use Resume Next - Nz not working here
        End If
    Next
    'add row
    If rows > 0 Then
        rs.Update
    Else
        Debug.Print
        Debug.Print "Source has " & fld & " fields."
        ' you could create a table here on the fly
        ' with field(0) being an autonumber key field, all others dbtext(255)
        ' then you re-open the Recordset
    End If
    rows = rows + 1: fld = 0
    If rows Mod 1000 = 0 Then
        DoEvents ' ability to interupt
    End If
Next
Import = rows
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Debug.Print "File imported in " & (Timer - tm) & " seconds. "
Exit Function
errH:
Resume Next
End Function
```

My data a file for this test was 31MB with 46K+ rows and 22 fields. I have other files upwards of 200MB.  This function took 52 seconds to load compared to 170 seconds using the OLEDB version. This tells me that the MSHTML.HTMLDocument dll is faster at interpreting an html file than Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 does.

---

UPDATE : While this solution worked well for source under 100MB when I started dealing with files of 200MB and 450MB this process was not efficient. My memory usage (task manager) went from 5GB to 15+GB in minutes and I could see page swapping starting to happen.

So, I abandoned the MSHTML.HTMLdocument way of doing things and loaded the files in memory using a binary read (Thanks Garcia [ECPTextStream](https://ws-garcia.github.io/ECPTextStream/home/getting_started.html)) function BinayWholeFileRead().
Next, use a byte array

```
Const LTTAG As Byte = 60, SLASH As Byte = 47, CHRT As Byte = 116
Dim aByte() as Byte, j as Long, k as Long
abyte = OutputStr ' the byte array points to the string's array of bytes
    If aByte(j) = LTTAG Then ' "<" we have the start of a tag
        If aByte(j + 2) = SLASH Then ' we have an end tag
            If aByte(j + 4) = CHRT Then  ' </t
```

Then, using j and k as pointers navigate thru the string and test the byte values against constants. I use k to find the beginning of the next tag to frame the string I needed to extract. I did not include the whole code as it was tailored for the SQL*Plus html output (one tag per line).
Once you find the content you want to put it in a string variable or a recordset.field:

```
ReDim tByte((k - j - 2) / 2) ' set a temp byte array to receive 
i = 0 ' pointer for tByte
For h = j To (k - 2) Step 2 ' step thru the source array
    tByte(i) = aByte(h) ' from one array to the other
    If tByte(i) = CHARSEMICOL Then hasAmp = True ' flag for html conversion Dim hasAmp as boolean
    i = i + 1 
    ' if you leave the Null byte between each ascii character the StrConv() will return " H E L L O   W O R L D" 
Next
str = StrConv(tByte(), vbUnicode) ' using the vbFromUnicode returns unintellegible ????
  ' call once in Fn Dim doc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument ' ref to Microsoft HTML Object Library required
    If hasAmp Then
        ' convert from html
        doc.body.innerHTML = str
        str = doc.body.innerText
        hasAmp = False 'reset flag
    End If
```

This is based on html file containing ASCII characters only.
The performance of this solution was 5 to 10 times better than my previous solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the HTML structure of Gord Thompsons solution there is a very fast way with ADO.

```
Public Function GetTitle(ByVal HtmlFile As String) As String
    Dim DOM As Object

    Set DOM = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    DOM.Load HtmlFile
    GetTitle = DOM.getElementsByTagName("title")(0).Text
End Function

Public Sub Import(ByVal Filename As String, ByVal Tablename As String)
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim Title As String
    On Error GoTo Import_Error

    Title = GetTitle(Filename)

    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "DROP TABLE " & Tablename

    SQL = "SELECT * INTO " & Tablename & _
          " FROM [HTML Import;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;DATABASE=" & Filename & "].[" & Title & "]"
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute SQL

    Exit Sub
Import_Error:
End Sub
```

So you want to get HTML file "C:\SomeFolder\MyFile.html" into the table "MyImport", use:

```
Import "C:\SomeFolder\MyFile.html", "MyImport"
```

One additional hint: If the title of the HTML-File has special characters like . or :, the import will fail. You have to try out which special Characters are problematic and which are not.

Comment: I tried the ADO solution but when dealing with large source files 100MB to 500MB I had time to go for lunch and it wasn't done.  Using the large string processing into byte array partial example I provided in my update it took about 5 minutes for a 450MB file.

Comment: @Jean-Marc Well, thanks for the hint. I only had to deal with smaller files with some KB. But why using HTML in files of that size? Is this quite a replacement for XML? If you are dealing with such amount of data, CSV would be my first choice. But, well, sometimes you get some of this stuff and have to deal with it. So, no offence...

Comment: well... if I had the choice I would be using .csv but I don't control the version of SQL*Plus that's available to me and my version can only extract into html, or fixed length text. Text is not a good choice for me dealing with large comment containing CrLf.

Comment: Well, these are actually some wierd options you were confronted with. And you are right, fixed length can be a nightmare, too.